# How do you "calibrate" (?) a matching network to re-optimize an S11 match based on physical measurements from a VNA?

Tags: rf, filter, impedance, measurement, impedance-matching

We made [EDA simulations to match an LNA input](https://youtu.be/xbdBjR4szjE) and had good results on the simulation (including EM simulation!) --- but when we built the board in real life the S11 match went from -30dB to -7dB. Ouch.

So now we're trying to figure out what went wrong.  We have collected a .s1p file from the physical result.  Can we use that to "calibrate" the current matching network state and then re-optimize the matching components to get a good 50 Ohm match?

Here is the EDA simulated match from the video linked above:

[image: LNA input S11 match]

As noted above, in simulation we get an S11 of about -30dB with EM (-21dB without EM) but when constructed and measured with a VNA we get about -7dB.  There is a bypass-relay and the signal is great in bypass, but the S11 problem appears with the LNA when the relay is on (power off defaults to bypass).

Questions:

- Can we somehow substitude the .s1p touchstone file from the VNA somewhere in the circuit above and re-optimize the match?
- Does it replace the LNA .s2p file somehow?

Keep in mind that while we could replace the original manufacturer's LNA .s2p file, but then the match would be *in addition* to the existing match.   We want to keep the existing topology (to avoid printing new boards) but change the components to values that would compensate for the error we measured physically.

The S21 output is fine, ~18dB gain.  Replacing the vendor .s2p with our .s1p (since S21 is ok) would be reasonable if we were de-embeded to pins but we are measuring from the SMA connectors.  Since we measure from the SMA connectors we would like to use our 7dB .s1p from the SMA's to inform a new match in the existing layout if that possible.

Frequency Range: 144 - 148 MHz. [This is the QPL9547 datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/412/QPL9547_Data_Sheet-1854301.pdf), vendor supports 0.1GHz to 6GHz

**This is the S11 from the datasheet, we are on the far left at 144MHz:**

[image: QPL9547 LNA S11]

**This is our VNA-measured S11:**

[image: VNA measured S11]

**This is the constructed device:**

[image: Constructed LNA]

**This is the RF gerber layer.**  Black holes drill holes, all holes are plated, most go to the ground plane (except the DC bias, see photo).  Port 1 is on the left, Port 2 is on the right.

[image: RF Gerber Layer for LNA]

Comment: I dont see the problem in using the s2p file, or extracting the S11 parameters from it. I guess it depends on where in the circuit your probe/cable were connected. How long are those connections between input and the components/LNA input? Could the transmission lines have an effect that you didnt take care of in the simulation?

Comment: @Linkyyy, I don't think you understood my question but I'm not sure what to clarify: We aren't extracting S11 from the original s2p, instead we have generated _our own_ .s1p from the constructed circuit with a VNA.  I want to use the .s1p from the VNA to somehow indicate which changes should be made to the original matching circuit, and then optimize new components based on the "real life" .s1p results.  How/where do I represent the .s1p in the original circuit to then optimize the components such that the result provides a "corrected" match with new component values but same layout?

Comment: Im sorry i did misread it. I dont see a problem with replacing the LNA two port model with a one port model with your real measured data, if you are not interested in the output

Comment: A chart showing the expected S11 (based on simulation) and the actual S11 (based on measurement) together could be helpful. Also a photo showing how the real circuit was constructed could help us identify what parasitics might be causing the real circuit to behave differently from the simulation.

Comment: Also, what frequency range did you test, and what frequency range do the vendor-supplied characteristic data for your capacitors and inductors cover?

Comment: Is inductor S3 really tied to ground, or does it go to a power supply that you're assuming is an AC ground for the purpose of simulation? If it's really grounded, was the s2p file for the amplifier measured with the same bias condition?

Comment: If the amplifier is Qorvo QPL9547, the datasheet does not recommend DC grounding of the input pin...and in fact says "a DC block is required". You should re-think your matching network to avoid applying DC bias to the input pin.

Comment: @ThePhoton, ok lots of article updates and pics:  You mentioned needing a DC block, thanks for pointing that out.  We _did_ try a 10nF cap below the S3 inductor to block the DC ground, but that made things worse (went from -7dB to -5dB) even though 10nF is definitely a low impedance path.